# Let $\frac{a}{b},\frac{c}{d}\in \mathbb{Q}$. prove that the product is well-defined

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

We have that $\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{d}=\frac{a'}{b'}\cdot\frac{c'}{d'}$, which can be rewritten as $\frac{ac}{bd} = \frac{a'c'}{b'd'}$ and again as $(ac)(b'd') = (bd)(a'c').$

If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a'}{b'}$ and $\frac{c}{d} = \frac{c'}{d'}, $ then $ab' = ba'$ and $cd' = dc'.$

$= (ab')(dd') = (ba')(dd')$ and $(cd')(bb') = (dc')(bb')$

$= (ab')(dd')(cd')(bb') = (ba')(dd')(dc')(bb')$ when multiplying the two equations.

Here is where I got stuck. I was attempting to get the final equation equal to $(ac)(b'd') = (bd)(a'c')$ so as to prove that the multiplication is well-defined, but I am unsure of how to get there from where I am or whether I'm thinking about this wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need to prove that $(ac)(b'd')=(bd)(a'c')$, but you're making it too complicated. By definition,

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a'}{b'} \: \: \text{and} \:\: \frac{c}{d} = \frac{c'}{d'}, $$

means that $ab' = ba'$ and $cd' = dc'$. By multiplying these two equations together (ie left times left, right times right) you simply get $(ac)(b'd')=(bd)(a'c')$, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @FruitManatee Glad I could help! Because you're new: If/when someone answers your question satisfactorily, you should accept it (by clicking the check below the answer score). This both gives reputation to the answerer (me), and helps others see that the question has been resolved when searching.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply say: 
$$\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}$$
which is always verified.
For the hypothesis done $\left (\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a_1}{b_1}, \frac{c_1}{d_1}=\frac{c}{d}\right)$, we arrive at:
$$\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a_1}{b_1}\cdot\frac{c_1}{d_1}$$

Comment: @Fruit Manatee: if it has been useful maybe a $+1$?